# search form doesn't show up

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building a toy Rails app. I generated a scaffold for my Post objects. Now, I want to add some search functionality to the scaffold generated view. I am following http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form to add the search functionality.

To app/views/posts/index.html.erb I add

```
<% form_tag posts_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
     <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]   %>
     <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and then the code for listings follow.

In controllers/posts_controller.rb I have

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
```

In model/post.rb I have

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image_url, :title
        validates :name, :presence => true
        validates :title, :presence => true,
                        :length => { :minimum => 5 }
  def self.search(search)
        if search
                find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE?', "%#{$search}%"])
        else
                find(:all)
        end
  end
end
```

When I run the server, I don't get any errors, but the form doesn't show up. I looked at the generated page source, and there is no form there. What is going on? Is there a way to debug situations like these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Rails 3 the `form_tag` helper itself return the html it produces. The equal sign is needed. So please change the first line to

```
<%= form_tag posts_path, :method => 'get' do %>
```

That was different in Rails 2. As the railscasts episode is quite old you may run into other issues as well.

See [the Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) as well.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, according to [Simple Search Form in Rails 3 App not Displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9151655/429850), I needed a `=` before the form_tag to indicate that this is a method.